# Possible conflict error using 443 port in IBM HTTP Server configuration

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, ibmhttpserver

I'm trying to get visibility of two IBM MobileFirst apps trough two different domains, with two different IHS configurations (independent HTTP Server and Plugin configurations) using the same secure port (443). I mean, I have *domain1.com* and *domain2.com*, and I need to use the port 443 to communicate with the public users.

My app server is an IBM Liberty Profile. I found a question related ([multiple domains at the same secure port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214475/multiple-domains-in-443-port-in-same-ip)) but is deployed on an IIS configuration.

The error that I can see at the log is:

> 192.168.252.123 - - [18/Apr/2017:04:29:36 -0400] "\x16\x03" 501 292

Googleing I found something related to this [error on an Apache configuration](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Apache2_Invalid_method_in_request_%5Cx16%5Cx03%5Cx01) and at the end of the article says:

> Probably you have a section with a specific VirtualHost IP address conflicting with the *default* VirtualHost. A section something like this "VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:443" cannot be used with the default section like this "VirtualHost *default*:443".

When I take a look in my httpd.conf file I can't find another mention of a virtualhost or the port that I use.

Is this configuration possible or is absolutely neccesary to use different secure ports for both apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is required to have two ports for two separate instances of an HTTP server, but it's generally not required to have two instances of an HTTP server simply to host two domain names.

Any release of IBM HTTP Server (IHS) can serve two certificates on two domains in one instance if the domains use a different IP address.

If they share an IP address, IHS prior to 9.0 requires a single certificate to be valid for both domains (wildcard, SubjectAltName).

IHS 9.0 supports SNI and 2 certs can be used on 2 domains with just a single IP address.  The 9.0 manual has many examples. You'd be using 2 *:443 Virtual Hosts.

Comment: Thanks @covener. I found a solution trough a balancer in front of my IHS configuration. It redirects all the traffic by the 443 port and I configure the IHS plugin to receive and send the request to the Liberty server by another internal port. Finally the Plugin is the glue between the web server and the app server. Could I mark your answer like the correct answer? It let me found a reasonable solution.

Comment: I'm a bit biased but I think it's reasonable.